# Rails Rmagick gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

just installed rmagick gem but having this error in my console while trying to upload :

```
LoadError (dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libclparser.dylib

  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.4.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle):
  app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:8
```

Could any one please help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please format your code. What is your image_uploader file ? can you paste it ( formatted )

Comment: Just to check, do you have imagemagick installed?

Comment: Is imagemagick installed and what OS are you using?

Comment: I just updated imagemagic through homebrew and got the same error

Answer (score 8):

It was happening here and I fixed it using:

```
    gem pristine rmagick
```

Done! :-)

Source: https://github.com/mroth/lolcommits/issues/9

Answer (score 5):

Ok i got it working now by

1. Uninstalling Imagemagick (i am using homebrew, so i run "brew remove imagemagick"
2. Uninstalling the rmagick gem ("gem uninstall rmagick")
3. Installing the rmagick gem again by running "bundle install"

I hope it helps

Comment: Just reinstalling rmagick was good enough for me. (Skipping step 1)

Comment: **These steps won't work if you don't reinstall `imagemagick` before reinstalling `rmagick`.** Besides, @SébastienGrosjean-ZenCocoon is right, you shouldn't need to touch `imagemagick`, just reinstall `rmagick`.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (Ubuntu 12.04, Rails 3.2.12):

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
```

and then:

```
bundle
```