# Rails and OS X: How to install rmagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-lion, homebrew, rmagick

I am already completely desperate - I spent whole day with trying to install `rmagick` gem to Mac OS X Lion, but literally it's a tragedy.
I saw many similar threads on Google, but nothing has helped me.

I tried completely uninstall `imagemagick` via `brew` and install it again (this is working well) and then to install the `rmagick`, but every time when I try to install this gem, I receive this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for clang... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick++... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
    --with-MagickCorelib
    --without-MagickCorelib
    --with-Magicklib
    --without-Magicklib
    --with-Magick++lib
    --without-Magick++lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

Doesn't matter if I will install the gem through Gemfile or through Terminal, in both cases I get the same error output.

This is the version of `imagemagick`: **imagemagick-6.8.0-10**.

Could you give me please some tips or advance, where could be the issue?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you `Check the mkmf.log file for more
details`?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know where to find this file (I've tried to search it through spootlight, but I've got lot of results).

Comment: Do you have the imagemagick development headers installed?

Comment: Linuxios - sorry, but how can I found out it?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h/30859701#30859701

Answer (score 74, accepted):

rmagick has a problem working with imagemagick (>= 6.8.0-10) from homebrew.

You can either

update `rmagick` gem by

```
    bundle update rmagick
```

or manually symbol link some dylib to make it work:

```
    $ cd "`Magick-config --prefix`lib"
    $ ln -s libMagick++-Q16.7.dylib   libMagick++.dylib
    $ ln -s libMagickCore-Q16.7.dylib libMagickCore.dylib
    $ ln -s libMagickWand-Q16.7.dylib libMagickWand.dylib
```

After that `gem install rmagick` should work.

Check the discussion about this in [homebrew/issues/16625](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16625)

Update:
Thanks @faraz for the nice one-liner command:

```
cd "`Magick-config --prefix`/lib"; ln -s libMagick++-Q8.7.dylib libMagick++.dylib; ln -s libMagickCore-Q8.7.dylib libMagickCore.dylib; ln -s libMagickWand-Q8.7.dylib libMagickWand.dylib
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for installing ImageMagick 6.8.10 using Homebrew and for installing RMagick 2.13.1. My environment uses RVM with Ruby 1.9.3-p327. Citation: https://coderwall.com/p/wnomjg

Comment: For 8-bit quantum depth: `cd "\`Magick-conifig --prefix\`/lib"; ln -s libMagick++-Q8.7.dylib libMagick++.dylib; ln -s libMagickCore-Q8.7.dylib libMagickCore.dylib; ln -s libMagickWand-Q8.7.dylib libMagickWand.dylib`

Comment: What @Sooie said. Updating `Gemfile.lock` helps with that.

Comment: Correct answer here, though I had trouble because my imagemagick installation was not in /usr/local but in /users/... folder. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I just want to say, that for me too, the folder is different. 

For me, the cd command is:
cd /Users/jackquack/.homebrew/Cellar

Comment: bundle update rmagick worked for me, rmagick is now at 2.13.2. I'm using ruby 1.9.3-p448

Comment: None of this did help me on Mac OS Mavericks. What did was a reinstall of the new XCode command line tools: `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Same as quantumpotato, I used only the first part (Update...) Not using homebrew, just normal install and cactuslab.com mac installer

Comment: Using 2.13.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 also fixed it for me.

Answer (score 41):

Mac OSX Sierra & Rails 5

```
brew unlink imagemagick
brew install imagemagick@6
brew link imagemagick@6 --force
```

Comment: most elegant solution

Comment: Can we make this the solution? 2012 is like a solution from the stoneedge

Answer (score 18):

#### I had the same problem.

If you check the mkmf.log, you'll see the following error message:

```
ld: library not found for -lgomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */\
```

### Here is how I solved it:

1. Uninstall current version of ImageMagick:

   `brew uninstall imagemagick`
2. Reinstall imagemagick without openmp support (this is the library responsible for lgomp):

   `brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp`
3. Install rmagick:

   `gem install rmagick`

Thats it!

Comment: For OSX 10.9 Mavericks, following the steps in this answer, and then follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17285359/914986, then running `gem install rmagick` will work.

Comment: Worked for me on OSX Lion.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using homebrew you just need to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH

```
brew install imagemagick
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick//6.8.9-1/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick
```

Comment: This seems to be a nice neat solution... Although strange since the actual `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` doesn't exist on my system

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me in Catalina:

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew install imagemagick@6
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH"
brew link --force imagemagick@6
brew install pkg-config
gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 5):

Try installing version 6.7.7-6 of imagemagick since version 6.8.x breaks the rmagick gem.

```
cd /usr/local
git checkout 7d951fb /usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
brew install imagemagick
```

Comment: Works for me on OS X Mavericks

Answer (score 5):

**As of 2017, all solutions suggested above not seem to work anymore, since ever Homebrew switched to ImageMagick 7.0.**

Some workarounds provided here.
https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/256

I just downgraded to ImageMagick 6.9.7-3 and `gem install rmagick` worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I am using this one-liner when I have issues with installing rmagick, which happens every time...

```
sudo C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-7/include/ImageMagick-6/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-7/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick
```

**Make sure the version of imagemagick is correct**, and you should be good to go. If you don't have imagemagick installed, do a `brew install imagemagick`.

---

Had to post this because I keep having issues installing this gem, and every time I forget how to do it.

Comment: It's 2018 and I was able to install the gem using the following procedure, I had to adjust the path to most recent versions and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

After you installed imagemagick, can you try

```
> gem pristine rmagick
```

Got it from this thread. [Rails Rmagick gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686192/rails-rmagick-gem). Hope it helps.

Comment: When I try to run this command, I'll get: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)    Failed to find gems ["rmagick"] >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can drop back to an older version of ImageMagick. [This thread](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16625) has instructions on how to do it:

> Now, to try and actually be useful I recommend you extract one of the
>   older bottles into your Cellar and then do brew link imagemagick if
>   you uninstalled the old version.
>
> They are available here:
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/machomebrew/files/Bottles/imagemagick-6.7.7-6.snowleopard.bottle.3.tar.gz/download
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/machomebrew/files/Bottles/imagemagick-6.7.7-6.lion.bottle.3.tar.gz/download
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/machomebrew/files/Bottles/imagemagick-6.7.7-6.mountainlion.bottle.3.tar.gz/download

Answer (score 0):

This is the fix for High Sierra, Mojave and Catalina,

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew install imagemagick@6export PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH"
brew link --force imagemagick@6
gem install rmagick
```

Source: https://blog.francium.tech/installing-rmagick-on-osx-high-sierra-7ea71f57390d