# Installing rmagick on mac lion

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

Find a lot of posts on it and followed what they say but does not work for me.

What i did

brew install imagemagick
gem install rmagick

it shows me following error

```
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.3.5... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick... no
Can't install RMagick 2.12.0. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it "ragick", or is it "rmagic"?

Comment: its rmagick, gem for ruby and imagemagick.

Comment: The title uses the term "ragick". Is this a typo, or is it intentional?

Comment: thanks for pointing out, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you'll find the answer. I had the same issue and this solved perfectly!

[Rails and OS X: How to install rmagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963404/rails-and-os-x-how-to-install-rmagick)