# command line tools for new 10.9 OSX for ruby gems?

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, command-line-tool

After installing OSX Mavericks 10.9 demo, Im getting this after running bundle

```
    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
extconf.rb:17: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for socket() in -lsocket... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
/Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
    from /Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func'
    from /Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:845:in `block in have_library'
    from /Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/sandric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:840:in `have_library'
    from extconf.rb:27:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/sandric/.bundler/tmp/5282/gems/libxml-ruby-2.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/sandric/.bundler/tmp/5282/gems/libxml-ruby-2.6.0/ext/libxml/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing libxml-ruby (2.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libxml-ruby -v '2.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I think that I do not have command line tools, so I tried to download some. It found out that there is no usual link for this in my XCode (it is 4, not 5, dont know why. If there is some way of installing fifth xcode - please help). So I went to apple developers webpage and not found command line tools for 10.9. I tried for 10.8 - it prints "Try install for 10.7", after trying with tools for 10.7 - it prints "try for 10.8".

Please, help. I'll provide all info for help.

Comment: I just tried to install a ruby gem and got the same error. Even in xcode5 the command line tools seem not to fix this issue

Answer (score 99, accepted):

TLDR:

```
xcode-select --install
```

In OS X 10.9, the command line developer tools are now installed on demand when they are used (this is the popup you mention seeing in a later comment).

The first time something tries to use one of the command line tools, the popup will be presented and the original command will return with a message that the command line tools need to be installed and with an error code. In this case, the problem is that the ruby process is hiding the message about the command line tools being needed.

If you wish to explicitly install the command line tools (instead of waiting for the popup to be triggered), you can run `xcode-select --install`. The command line tools package is also available as an independent download from http://developer.apple.com/downloads.

Note that if you have Xcode installed on your system, you should no longer need the separate command line tools package, the tools in /usr/bin will automatically use the ones located inside of the Xcode application. This is why the Xcode UI no longer offers the option to install the command line tools for you.

Comment: Even if you have Xcode installed, it needs to be Xcode *5* and xcode-select needs to point to that specific Xcode. That fixed it for me.

Comment: I think I need to point to that specific Xcode too... But how do I do that?

Comment: For me, it didn't work after only running "xcode-select --install", but did work after doing both that and starting Xcode and following the prompts there as well.

Answer (score 15):

For others running into this problem, I had to also install apple-gcc via brew to get it to work:

`brew install apple-gcc42`

Comment: This is also what worked for me.  Does anyone have any idea why this is required of (seemingly) only some of us?

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem installing gems after upgrading to OSX Mavericks. I saw this among the error messages:

```
make: gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
```

Which suggested that it's having trouble finding gcc. When I type "ls /usr/bin", I see that I have "gcc" but not "gcc-4.2". So I set up a symlink to tell it to look in "gcc" instead of "gcc-4.2", like so:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

This fixed my problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is what did it for me with xcode 5.0.2 already installed.

Comment: You put an end to 3 hours of pain (banging my head against a wall). Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I had to run both `xcode-select --install` and `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2` to get bundle to install `ffi`

Answer (score 1):

XCode 5.0.2 on Mavericks gave me the same error. 
Seems it wasn't fixed in 5.0.1 as expected.

Trying `xcode-select -- install` brought up a dialog to install command line tools (which I'd already done twice), but failed because they "weren't found on the server". Maybe this approach is outdated?

biobonnie's solution above worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

After that, cocoapods finally install properly! Thanks! 
(Would upvote, but can't yet ... )

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but Vyke's solution was helpful/required for me. My path to success after updating to mavericks was the following:

- Install xcode from the appstore (terminal couldn't find it find it on the server)
- Open xcode and accept the terms
- Use biobonnie's solution to move the GCC file
- rvm system
- rvm get head
- gem install yourgemname (in my case json)
- bundle install
- gem update rake

... and then I could get back to updating our jekyll/octopress based website.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded mountain lion to mavericks and received the above message.

I ended up launching XCode and it asked to install components automatically. After that was completed I re-bundled and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using Ruby version manager (rvm) the following worked for me.

Before you run the following, be sure to verify the symbolic link in /Users/yourusername/.rvm/rubies/.  Mine looks like this...

```
default -> /Users/yourusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429
```

If your sym link isn't set correctly, you can set it using...

```
cd /Users/yourusername/.rvm/rubies/
ln -s /Users/yourusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429 default
```

Then run the following from the command line

```
rvm system
rvm gemset export system.gems
rvm 1.9.3 #use your Ruby version here
rvm gemset import system.gems
```

now you should be ready to install your gems

```
gem install yourgemname
```

Comment: I didnt understant your point and how this corresponds with theme of topic, sorry(

Comment: Your issue is a gem extension build error.  This response was intended to help you reset your ruby version and gemset which should resolve your issue.