# Ruby/Mavericks 10.9/Xcode 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line-tool, xcode5, osx-mavericks

I'm attempting to install the Nokogiri gem on Ruby 2.0.0 while using Mavericks 10.9 along w/ Xcode 5 but I keep getting the error

```
You have to install development tools first
```

I downloaded and installed the command line tools for Mavericks from Apple's developer site so I'm not really sure what the problem is.

I've attempted the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066849/command-line-tools-for-new-10-9-osx-for-ruby-gems?rq=1) but when inputting `xcode-select --install` into the terminal I just get back the help menu at --install doesn't seem to be a valid argument

```
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
```

Comment: Did you read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066849/command-line-tools-for-new-10-9-osx-for-ruby-gems?rq=1)?

Comment: I had read that before posting but to no success

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue after I installed Mavericks. Entering this in the command-line worked for me:

> xcode-select --install

Installs the latest version of command-line tools; no need to deal with ADC!

Comment: Yep! Works great on Mavericks

Answer (score 0):

first

> ```
> xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> ```

Then, since mavericks has not yet been released, there is a bug in the Ruby header file.

You should try this solution 
https://gist.github.com/goshakkk/5763489
WITH a Xcode5 DP version.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5.0.1 solves the Ruby header problem. It is currently available from Apple's developer site.