# Install cocoa pods on mavericks

Tags: ios, cocoapods, osx-mavericks

I intalled mavericks this morning on my mac, but it seems it has done something with ruby gems... When i type:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

It breaks with error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
```

I browsed net and found this, some people say that it helps, but before doing it can anyone elaborate some more on this:

```
sys_rb_usr=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr
sdk_rb_usr=`xcode-select -p`/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr
sudo cp -r $sdk_rb_usr/include $sys_rb_usr/include
```

Will copying this solve a problem, and if it doesn't am I in danger of losing something?

Comment: Looks like this may have been fixed with Xcode 5.0.1 from the MAS. https://gist.github.com/goshakkk/5763489#comment-931445

Comment: It seems you are right, i updated today to 5.0.1, and seems ok. Post as an answer so i can give credit where it is due.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this may have been fixed with Xcode 5.0.1 from the MAS. https://gist.github.com/goshakkk/5763489#comment-931445

Answer (score 9):

As an update since this question is a few months old:

I have XCode 5.0.2 installed on OS X Mavericks and ran into the exact same issue.
The issue may have been fixed with XCode 5.0.1, but something broke again...

I'd downloaded/installed XCode command line tools for Mavericks w/o success.
Next tried the solution above w/no success.

What finally worked for me was sym link gcc to gcc-4.2 as explained here:
[command line tools for new 10.9 OSX for ruby gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066849/command-line-tools-for-new-10-9-osx-for-ruby-gems?rq=1)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

After that, cocoapods finally installed properly.