# Can't install cocoapods on mavericks

Tags: ruby, xcode, cocoapods, rubymotion

I am having issues installing the gem motion-cocoapods on mavericks. I am using ruby 1.9.3-p484, OS X Mavericks, Xcode 5.1.

I found lots of solutions but none of them work.

Here is my error logs when trying to install

```
checking for -std=c99 option to compiler... yes
checking for CoreFoundation... no
checking for main() in -lCoreFoundation... no
CoreFoundation is needed to build the Xcodeproj C extension.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

**xcode/mkmf.log file**

```
checking for -std=c99 option to compiler... -------------------- yes

"/usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6 -o conftest -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.1.0 -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L.  -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib      -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"/usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6 -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.1.0 -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include  -fno-common -pipe  -std=c99 -c conftest.c"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
/* end */

--------------------

have_framework: checking for CoreFoundation... -------------------- no

"/usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6 -o conftest -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.1.0 -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include  -fno-common -pipe -std=c99 conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L.  -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib      -lruby.1.9.1 -ObjC -framework CoreFoundation -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
cc1: error: argument to '-O' should be a non-negative integer
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
4: 
5: int main(void){return 0;}
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for main() in -lCoreFoundation... -------------------- no

"/usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6 -o conftest -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.1.0 -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include  -fno-common -pipe -std=c99 conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L.  -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib      -lruby.1.9.1 -lCoreFoundation  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:4:53: error: 'main' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:4:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

"/usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6 -o conftest -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.1.0 -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include  -fno-common -pipe -std=c99 conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L.  -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib      -lruby.1.9.1 -lCoreFoundation  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:4:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'main' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
ld: library not found for -lCoreFoundation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { main(); return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Here is some solutions I have tried

**Reinstall Xcode & point to it**

```
xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

**Ran the following command** ([command line tools for new 10.9 OSX for ruby gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066849/command-line-tools-for-new-10-9-osx-for-ruby-gems?rq=1))

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

**Ran this command** (https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/192)

```
CFLAGS="-F /System/Library/Frameworks" gem install motion-cocoapods -- --with-ldflags="-F/System/Library/Frameworks"
```

Comment: How about posting the relevant contents of the `mkmf.log` file?

Comment: Did you try `xcode-select --install` ?

Comment: I have tried that but I got the following error `can't install the software because it is not currently available from the software update server.`. I found a fix for this and downloaded the xcode command line tools separately from the apple developer website https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-. And I am still getting the same errors

Comment: I think the following error: `cc1: error: argument to '-O' should be a non-negative integer` is referring to the `-ObjC` flag. I'm not a gcc geek so I can't make any detailed speculation. However, I do believe (gut feeling) it's the command-line tools that are somehow wrong here. Sorry I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms on Mac OS 10.9, rvm 1.25.22, ruby-1.9.3-p484, while trying to run `gem install cocoapods`; the issue was that I had both gcc-4.6 and gcc-4.2 installed.

RVM apparently decided to run `brew install gcc46` for me automatically when I installed a ruby:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3-p484
Checking requirements for osx.
Error: No available formula for gcc46 
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system....
Installing required custom packages: homebrew/versions.
Installing required packages: gcc46...
```

My mkmf.log (like yours) showed that compilation was using gcc-4.6 and failing.  The fix for me was to `brew uninstall gcc46`, `rvm uninstall 1.9.3-p484`, then `brew install apple-gcc42` and `rvm install 1.9.3-p484` again.

With a fresh ruby built from apple-gcc42, and no trace of gcc46 left on my system, `gem install cocoapods` worked.  No other uninstallation or reinstallation was necessary.